# AJAX close popup modal onsuccess download

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a link that calls a page to generate a CSV file.
This all works OK however when the link is clicked I am opening popup modal.

How can I close the pop up when the CSV file is loaded?

This is what I have so far:

```
 $(function () {
   $('.export').on('click', function () {
     $('#generateCSVModal').modal('show');
       $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '/Download/CSV/' + @Model.CSVID,
         data: form,
         success: function (data) {
                    $('#generateCSVModal').modal('hide');
         }
       });
       return false;
    });
  });
```

Comment: why `return false;` - everything else in your code is fine, does it work as expected?

Comment: Are you able to breakpoint on `success`? Perhaps add an error handling.

Comment: Pop up modal opens.
CSV is generated and loaded.

However popup modal does not close once the file is loaded.

Comment: Have you tried this ? $('#generateCSVModal').modal("toggle");

Comment: let us know if you are getting any error in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this is the solution:

```
$(function () {
        $('.export').on('click', function () {

            $('#generateCSVModal').modal('show');


            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Download/CSV/' + @Model.CSVID,
                dataType: "text",

                success: function (data) {
                    csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data);
                    $('#generateCSVModal').modal('hide');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```